# Warning-free Templating in C

Tags: c, data-structures, casting, templating, gcc-warning

Transitioning from C++, I am now learning the dark art of C and have developed the following code to replace my need for templating.  In the bottom example, I have implemented your garden-variety Node structure in such a way that it can be used to store any data type. Consider the following...

```
// vptr.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node
{  
    void* data;
    struct Node* next;
};

int main()
{  
    struct Node n0, n1;

    n0.next = &n1;
    n0.data = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *((int*) n0.data) = 3;

    printf("%d\n",  *((int*) n0.data));

    return 0;
}
```

Again, the issue lies with **warning free** compilation of this code--namely using the gcc compiler, though my wxDevCpp for Windows also gives me some warnings but is much less fussy about it.  I blame it on the GUI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the possible types are limited, you could use a big union (which could still contain a void-pointer  in case you want to point to a struct).  Or you could use a byte-vector (e.g. unsigned char [8]) that's just big enough to store any possible data type and use memcpy to store data and casting to get data from it).

Comment: when are unions worth using? that is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, just adding the correct include for malloc (`<stdlib.h>`) makes your code compile warning free with: `gcc -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` is declared in stdlib.h, which you did not include. So if you add the `#include`, the warning goes away.

The other warning is about `//` which is not a valid comment in C89. To make that warning go away use `/* */` for comments or tell gcc to use C99.

Comment: thanks guys. i was so proud of my syntax, now i feel retarde ;P

Comment: I would say "declared in" instead of "defined in", and declaration is what that matters to the user programmer.